# How to use SentiWordNet

Tags: java, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I need to do sentiment analysis on some csv files containing tweets. I'm using [SentiWordNet](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/) to do the sentiment analysis.

I got the following piece of sample java code they provided on their site. I'm not sure how to use it. The path of the csv file that I want to analyze is `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\tweets.csv` . The path of the `SentiWordNet_3.0.0.txt` is `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\SentiWordNet_3.0.0\home\swn\www\admin\dump\SentiWordNet_3.0.0_20130122.txt` . I'm new to java, pls help, thanks! The link to the sample java code below is [this](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/code/SWN3.java).

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Vector;

public class SWN3 {
    private String pathToSWN = "data"+File.separator+"SentiWordNet_3.0.0.txt";
    private HashMap<String, String> _dict;

    public SWN3(){

        _dict = new HashMap<String, String>();
        HashMap<String, Vector<Double>> _temp = new HashMap<String, Vector<Double>>();
        try{
            BufferedReader csv =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToSWN));
            String line = "";           
            while((line = csv.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] data = line.split("\t");
                Double score = Double.parseDouble(data[2])-Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
                String[] words = data[4].split(" ");
                for(String w:words)
                {
                    String[] w_n = w.split("#");
                    w_n[0] += "#"+data[0];
                    int index = Integer.parseInt(w_n[1])-1;
                    if(_temp.containsKey(w_n[0]))
                    {
                        Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(w_n[0]);
                        if(index>v.size())
                            for(int i = v.size();i<index; i++)
                                v.add(0.0);
                        v.add(index, score);
                        _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Vector<Double> v = new Vector<Double>();
                        for(int i = 0;i<index; i++)
                            v.add(0.0);
                        v.add(index, score);
                        _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                    }
                }
            }
            Set<String> temp = _temp.keySet();
            for (Iterator<String> iterator = temp.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                String word = (String) iterator.next();
                Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(word);
                double score = 0.0;
                double sum = 0.0;
                for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
                    score += ((double)1/(double)(i+1))*v.get(i);
                for(int i = 1; i<=v.size(); i++)
                    sum += (double)1/(double)i;
                score /= sum;
                String sent = "";               
                if(score>=0.75)
                    sent = "strong_positive";
                else
                if(score > 0.25 && score<=0.5)
                    sent = "positive";
                else
                if(score > 0 && score>=0.25)
                    sent = "weak_positive";
                else
                if(score < 0 && score>=-0.25)
                    sent = "weak_negative";
                else
                if(score < -0.25 && score>=-0.5)
                    sent = "negative";
                else
                if(score<=-0.75)
                    sent = "strong_negative";
                _dict.put(word, sent);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}        
    }

    public String extract(String word, String pos)
    {
        return _dict.get(word+"#"+pos);
    }
}
```

Newcode:

```
public class SWN3 {
        private String pathToSWN = "C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\SentiWordNet_3.0.0\\home\\swn\\www\\admin\\dump\\SentiWordNet_3.0.0.txt";
    private HashMap<String, String> _dict;

    public SWN3(){

        _dict = new HashMap<String, String>();
        HashMap<String, Vector<Double>> _temp = new HashMap<String, Vector<Double>>();
        try{
            BufferedReader csv =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToSWN));
            String line = "";           
            while((line = csv.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] data = line.split("\t");
                Double score = Double.parseDouble(data[2])-Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
                String[] words = data[4].split(" ");
                for(String w:words)
                {
                    String[] w_n = w.split("#");
                    w_n[0] += "#"+data[0];
                    int index = Integer.parseInt(w_n[1])-1;
                    if(_temp.containsKey(w_n[0]))
                    {
                        Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(w_n[0]);
                        if(index>v.size())
                            for(int i = v.size();i<index; i++)
                                v.add(0.0);
                        v.add(index, score);
                        _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Vector<Double> v = new Vector<Double>();
                        for(int i = 0;i<index; i++)
                            v.add(0.0);
                        v.add(index, score);
                        _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                    }
                }
            }
            Set<String> temp = _temp.keySet();
            for (Iterator<String> iterator = temp.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                String word = (String) iterator.next();
                Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(word);
                double score = 0.0;
                double sum = 0.0;
                for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
                    score += ((double)1/(double)(i+1))*v.get(i);
                for(int i = 1; i<=v.size(); i++)
                    sum += (double)1/(double)i;
                score /= sum;
                String sent = "";               
                if(score>=0.75)
                    sent = "strong_positive";
                else
                if(score > 0.25 && score<=0.5)
                    sent = "positive";
                else
                if(score > 0 && score>=0.25)
                    sent = "weak_positive";
                else
                if(score < 0 && score>=-0.25)
                    sent = "weak_negative";
                else
                if(score < -0.25 && score>=-0.5)
                    sent = "negative";
                else
                if(score<=-0.75)
                    sent = "strong_negative";
                _dict.put(word, sent);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}        
    }

    public Double extract(String word)
    {
        Double total = new Double(0);
        if(_dict.get(word+"#n") != null)
             total = _dict.get(word+"#n") + total;
        if(_dict.get(word+"#a") != null)
            total = _dict.get(word+"#a") + total;
        if(_dict.get(word+"#r") != null)
            total = _dict.get(word+"#r") + total;
        if(_dict.get(word+"#v") != null)
            total = _dict.get(word+"#v") + total;
        return total;
    }

    public String classifytweet(){
        String[] words = twit.split("\\s+"); 
        double totalScore = 0, averageScore;
        for(String word : words) {
            word = word.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z\\s])", "");
            if (_sw.extract(word) == null)
                continue;
            totalScore += _sw.extract(word);
        }
        Double AverageScore = totalScore;

        if(averageScore>=0.75)
            return "very positive";
        else if(averageScore > 0.25 && averageScore<0.5)
            return  "positive";
        else if(averageScore>=0.5)
            return  "positive";
        else if(averageScore < 0 && averageScore>=-0.25)
            return "negative";
        else if(averageScore < -0.25 && averageScore>=-0.5)
            return "negative";
        else if(averageScore<=-0.75)
            return "very negative";
        return "neutral";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all start by deleting all the "garbage" at the first of the file (which includes description, instruction etc..)

One possible usage is to change `SWN3` an make the method `extract` in it return a `Double`:

```
public Double extract(String word)
{
    Double total = new Double(0);
    if(_dict.get(word+"#n") != null)
         total = _dict.get(word+"#n") + total;
    if(_dict.get(word+"#a") != null)
        total = _dict.get(word+"#a") + total;
    if(_dict.get(word+"#r") != null)
        total = _dict.get(word+"#r") + total;
    if(_dict.get(word+"#v") != null)
        total = _dict.get(word+"#v") + total;
    return total;
}
```

Then, giving a String that you want to tag, you can split it so it'll have only words (with no signs and unknown chars) and using the result returned from `extract` method on each word, you can decide what is the average weight of the String:

```
String[] words = twit.split("\\s+"); 
double totalScore = 0, averageScore;
for(String word : words) {
    word = word.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z\\s])", "");
    if (_sw.extract(word) == null)
        continue;
    totalScore += _sw.extract(word);
}
verageScore = totalScore;

if(averageScore>=0.75)
    return "very positive";
else if(averageScore > 0.25 && averageScore<0.5)
    return  "positive";
else if(averageScore>=0.5)
    return  "positive";
else if(averageScore < 0 && averageScore>=-0.25)
    return "negative";
else if(averageScore < -0.25 && averageScore>=-0.5)
    return "negative";
else if(averageScore<=-0.75)
    return "very negative";
return "neutral";
```

I found this way easier and it works fine for me.

---

**UPDATE:**

I changed `_dict` to `_dict = new HashMap<String, Double>();` So it will have a `String` key and a `Double` value.

So I replaced `_dict.put(word, sent);` wish `_dict.put(word, score);`

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I'm still not clear on some parts. What does this mean? if(_dict.get(word+"#r") != null) #n,#a,#r,#v ? Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the first column of the file, you'll notice these letters (which stands for *noun*, *verb*..) so you should cover all the cases.

Comment: Ah I see. I still need a bit more help, where to I put my link to my tweet.csv file? C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\tweets.csv I pasted my updated code above, pls feel free to edit it, thanks!

Comment: Sorry for asking so much, Haha.. I'm new, would really appreciate it! =)

Comment: @Belgarion I don't understand your question, can you please explain it one more time? And feel free to ask whatever you want :)

Comment: Thanks! :) For this statement, total = _dict.get(word+"#n") + total; , it gives me an error. It says _dict.get(word+"#n") is a string. Is there anything I should change?

Comment: Hi, I tried making the code work but I'm getting zero score, I really don't know why. My friend posted a question regarding this

Comment: Here's the link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847025/getting-incorrect-score-using-sentiwordnet

Comment: Shouldn't `extract()` give an average of scores for #n, #a, #r, #v? By merely adding them, you are giving more weights to words that appear more in these four category. In other words, a word that appears in all four categories with score 0.25 will have a word that appears in only one category with score 1, even though the latter is a strongly positive word. Also, the score can exceed 1. Running your code with the word 'good' gives a score of 1.093678792140053, which is outside of the range of scores from -1 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

for that you should write the main function, in that provide the path of csv, extract words from it. and then call extract function by sending the word and its pos.