# Getting incorrect Score using SentiWordNet

Tags: java, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I'm doing some sentiment analysis using SentiWordNet and I referred to the post here [How to use SentiWordNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653091/how-to-use-sentiwordnet) . However, I'm getting a score of 0.0 despite trying out various inputs. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class SWN3 {
        private String pathToSWN = "C:\\Users\\Malcolm\\Desktop\\SentiWordNet_3.0.0\\home\\swn\\www\\admin\\dump\\SentiWordNet_3.0.0.txt";
        private HashMap<String, Double> _dict;

        public SWN3(){

            _dict = new HashMap<String, Double>();
            HashMap<String, Vector<Double>> _temp = new HashMap<String, Vector<Double>>();
            try{
                BufferedReader csv =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToSWN));
                String line = "";           
                while((line = csv.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String[] data = line.split("\t");
                    Double score = Double.parseDouble(data[2])-Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
                    String[] words = data[4].split(" ");
                    for(String w:words)
                    {
                        String[] w_n = w.split("#");
                        w_n[0] += "#"+data[0];
                        int index = Integer.parseInt(w_n[1])-1;
                        if(_temp.containsKey(w_n[0]))
                        {
                            Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(w_n[0]);
                            if(index>v.size())
                                for(int i = v.size();i<index; i++)
                                    v.add(0.0);
                            v.add(index, score);
                            _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Vector<Double> v = new Vector<Double>();
                            for(int i = 0;i<index; i++)
                                v.add(0.0);
                            v.add(index, score);
                            _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Set<String> temp = _temp.keySet();
                for (Iterator<String> iterator = temp.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                    String word = (String) iterator.next();
                    Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(word);
                    double score = 0.0;
                    double sum = 0.0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
                        score += ((double)1/(double)(i+1))*v.get(i);
                    for(int i = 1; i<=v.size(); i++)
                        sum += (double)1/(double)i;
                    score /= sum;
                    String sent = "";               
                    if(score>=0.75)
                        sent = "strong_positive";
                    else
                    if(score > 0.25 && score<=0.5)
                        sent = "positive";
                    else
                    if(score > 0 && score>=0.25)
                        sent = "weak_positive";
                    else
                    if(score < 0 && score>=-0.25)
                        sent = "weak_negative";
                    else
                    if(score < -0.25 && score>=-0.5)
                        sent = "negative";
                    else
                    if(score<=-0.75)
                        sent = "strong_negative";
                    _dict.put(word, score);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}        
        }

public Double extract(String word)
{
    Double total = new Double(0);
    if(_dict.get(word+"#n") != null)
         total = _dict.get(word+"#n") + total;
    if(_dict.get(word+"#a") != null)
        total = _dict.get(word+"#a") + total;
    if(_dict.get(word+"#r") != null)
        total = _dict.get(word+"#r") + total;
    if(_dict.get(word+"#v") != null)
        total = _dict.get(word+"#v") + total;
    return total;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SWN3 test = new SWN3();
    String sentence="Hello have a Super awesome great day";
    String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+"); 
    double totalScore = 0;
    for(String word : words) {
        word = word.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z\\s])", "");
        if (test.extract(word) == null)
            continue;
        totalScore += test.extract(word);
    }
    System.out.println(totalScore);
}

}
```

Here's the first 10 lines of SentiWordNet.txt

```
a   00001740    0.125   0   able#1  (usually followed by `to') having the necessary means or skill or know-how or authority to do something; "able to swim"; "she was able to program her computer"; "we were at last able to buy a car"; "able to get a grant for the project"
a   00002098    0   0.75    unable#1    (usually followed by `to') not having the necessary means or skill or know-how; "unable to get to town without a car"; "unable to obtain funds"
a   00002312    0   0   dorsal#2 abaxial#1  facing away from the axis of an organ or organism; "the abaxial surface of a leaf is the underside or side facing away from the stem"
a   00002527    0   0   ventral#2 adaxial#1 nearest to or facing toward the axis of an organ or organism; "the upper side of a leaf is known as the adaxial surface"
a   00002730    0   0   acroscopic#1    facing or on the side toward the apex
a   00002843    0   0   basiscopic#1    facing or on the side toward the base
a   00002956    0   0   abducting#1 abducent#1  especially of muscles; drawing away from the midline of the body or from an adjacent part
a   00003131    0   0   adductive#1 adducting#1 adducent#1  especially of muscles; bringing together or drawing toward the midline of the body or toward an adjacent part
a   00003356    0   0   nascent#1   being born or beginning; "the nascent chicks"; "a nascent insurgency"
a   00003553    0   0   emerging#2 emergent#2   coming into existence; "an emergent republic"
```

Comment: I ran your program and I got 0.9087554089349004. Can you post the first 10 lines of your `SentiWord.txt` file?

Comment: Just posted the first 10 lines

Comment: Did you remove all the comments from the top of the file?

Comment: Yes Sir, removed the top portion which contained the comments. The above is the top 10 lines of the SentiWordNet.3.0.0.txt

Comment: You ran the same code I posted without editing it?

Comment: The same exact code. I only changed the path to my SentiWord.txt

Comment: I ran the code above in eclipse and I got the following:

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
0.0
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at SWN3.<init>(SWN3.java:23)
 at SWN3.main(SWN3.java:99)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27686/discussion-between-maroun-maroun-and-malcolm-x)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the `SentiWord.txt` file comes with a weird format.

You need to remove the first part of it (which includes comments and instructions) and the last two lines:

```
#
EMPTY LINE
```

The parser doesn't know how to handle these situations, if you delete these extra two lines you'll be fine.

Comment: @MarounMaroun what is the meaning of #1, #2 in the sentiwordnet.txt file? Please help me too. for example: a   00002730    0   0   acroscopic#1    facing or on the side toward the apex  .... Thanks in advance.

Comment: HI @Faizal i got java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2, what went wrong?