# .jcall error in R: cannot determine object class

Tags: java, r, rjava

I've been trying to develop R code that is using a function built in Java, but I'm having an error with .jcall.

The code built in Java can be found here: [Getting incorrect Score using SentiWordNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847025/getting-incorrect-score-using-sentiwordnet?rq=1)

I've managed to create the .class and the .jar files.
From the cmd window, I can check that my function returns an object of type double.

The code I'm running in R is the following:

```
.jinit(".")

.jaddClassPath("D:\\Users\\cristina.cerqueira\\Documents\\R\\win-library\\3.0\\SWN3\\SWN3.jar")
.jaddClassPath("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_55\\lib\\SWN3.jar")
.jclassPath()


.jinit(".")
c <- .jnew("SWN3")

jSWR3 <-function(s) {

    result= .jcall("Ljava/lang/String", returnSig = "D", method=c, as.character(s),
            evalArray = TRUE, check = TRUE, evalString = TRUE,
            .jcast( rJava:::.rJava.class.loader,"java/lang/ClassLoader" ) )  

}

s <- c("love","v")
jSWR3(s)
```

The error is the following:

```
Error in .jcall("Ljava/lang/String", returnSig = "D", method = c, as.character(s),  : 
  RcallMethod: cannot determine object class
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: doesn't that big whitespace in your path give you troubles? also using `c` as both a function and an object name?

Comment: thanks for your comment! the whitespace was my bad copying the code into the question; i've replaced _method = c_ by _method = "SWN3"_ and the error continues to be the same