# R functions using SentiWordNet

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, tm, senti-wordnet

I am doing sentiment analysis and text mining on an e-mail box dedicated for client feedback.  I use R for this work.  I based the sentiment analysis on the work done by Jeffrey Breen.  It works fine but I want to take it a step further.  During my research I came across SentiWordnet.

I searched for R-code/functions to be able to apply SentiWordNet but only came up with Java and Python resources.  I am not at all familiar with either of these.

Is there someone who applied SentiWordNet in R?  I will appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any example of SentiWordNet accessed solely from R, however you could call the [Python package](http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiwordnet.html) from R using [rPython](http://rpython.r-forge.r-project.org/), or the [Java implementation](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/code/SWN3.java) using [rJava](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html) (some notes provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653091/how-to-use-sentiwordnet)). Unfortunately the python implementation is not currently available for Windows.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I will definitely give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2019 the Lexicon package by Tyler Rinker (available on CRAN) contains the SentiWordnet dataset.